# Jasmine testing Angular app with different browsers

Tags: angular, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I want run my tests locally with Chrome as browser and on the build server with phantomjs. How can I configure that in the karma.conf.js file

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-trx-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './<%= sourceDir %>/test.ts', watched: false },
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './<%= sourceDir %>/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
      ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul', 'trx']
      : ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'trx'],
    trxReporter: {
      outputFile: 'test-results.trx',
      shortTestName: false
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

on my build server I use this config:

```
browsers: ['PhantomJs'],
singleRun: true
```

I run the tests on my build server by running npm test, which launches ng test.
Is there a way to configure that directly on this config file or I should use different karma.conf.js files? And how I should use this. Or should I use some arguments on ng test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a nice and simple solution by using some scripts in my package config

```
"test": "ng test --single-run --browsers=PhantomJS",
"test.watch": "ng test --browsers=Chrome",
```

Answer (score 1):

What i did is used 2 different npm scripts to trigger the test (basically run karma start), called `test` and `test-chrome`. Then in karma.conf.js I did this before `module.exports`:

```
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isChrome= ENV === 'test-chrome';
```

and in the config:

```
browsers: isChrome? ['Chrome'] : ['PhantomJS']
```

In your case, you could run test-chrome locally, and just test on the build server.